# I cant Play music that through MediaPlayer i have recorded

Tags: android, media-player

The Path where the file is located "/storage/sdcard/MediaRecorderSample/Recordingg2"
The errors i am getting

```
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1,E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0),D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Here is my code

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    static MediaPlayer mp;
    SeekBar sb;
    ArrayList mysongs;
    int pos;
    Uri u;
    Thread th;
    String filepath;
    File file;
    Button btprev,btfb,btplay,btff,btnext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        filepath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
         file = new File(filepath,"MediaRecorderSample");


        btplay=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btplay);
        btff=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btff);
        btnext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnxt);
        btprev=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btprev);
        btfb=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btfb);

        btplay.setOnClickListener(this);
        btff.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnext.setOnClickListener(this);
        btfb.setOnClickListener(this);
        btprev.setOnClickListener(this);

        sb= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        th = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int totalduration= mp.getDuration();
                int currentposition=0;
                sb.setMax(totalduration);
                while(currentposition < totalduration)
                {
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        currentposition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        sb.setProgress(currentposition);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //super.run();
            }
        };

       // if(mp!=null)
       // {
          //  mp.stop();
          //  mp.reset();
          //  mp.release();
      //  }



        Intent i = getIntent();

        Bundle b= i.getExtras();

        pos = b.getInt("pos");
       mysongs= b.getStringArrayList("mysongs");
        Log.d("Mystring", String.valueOf(mysongs));
        Log.d("path1",file.getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + mysongs.get(pos));


        u = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + mysongs.get(pos)+".wav");
        //mp.create(getApplicationContext(),u);

        try {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
            //mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            th.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
       // try {
          //  mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
           // mp.start();

       // } catch (IOException e) {
          //  e.printStackTrace();
       // }



        //mp.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.btplay:
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    btplay.setText(">");
                    mp.pause();
                }
                else {
                    btplay.setText("||");
                    mp.start();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btff:

                mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()+ 5000);

                break;
            case R.id.btfb:
                mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
                break;

            case R.id.btnxt:
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                pos =(pos+1)%mysongs.size();
                u = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()+ "/"+mysongs.get(pos).toString());
                // mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btprev:
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                pos =(pos-1<0)? mysongs.size()-1: pos-1;

               u= Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()+ "/"+mysongs.get(pos).toString());
                // mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: there is a problem in your code I'm sure. Also does your file play with a regullar android player?

Comment: ya when i play from any file manager or directly by clicking on the file it plays... bt when i am trying through with app it gives error, E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1,E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0),D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Comment: then the problem is in your code.

Comment: so what to do can you share me some code ?? or may i show you my code??

Comment: since the problem is in **your** code, why would I need to share some of my?

Comment: i have given my code

Comment: I've formatted your code, and will try to look into it now

Comment: ok, you should first check if your MediaPlayer is playing before stopping it. So if it is not playing, then it does not need to be stopped. This might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: thanks actually i am new to android in learning phase

Comment: i did it nothing happend

Comment: then show the updated code